# Transverse waves on a system of two strings of different densities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves

There are two strings made from different materials (different densities $\rho_{Al}, \rho_{Fe}$), but the same cross-section $S$. Each of them has a different length ($l_1$, $l_2$) and they are connected seamlessly to each other, the first one is tied to a wall, the second one has a weight $m$ on its end (connected through a pulley). The situation illustrates the picture below.

[image]

There is a wave on these two connected strings such that there is a knot at the wall ($x = 0$), at the pulley ($x = l_1 + l_2$) and at the connection of the two strings ($x = l_1$).

I would like to find out the lowest possible frequency for which all the conditions hold and there is a transverse wave.

My solution so far:

I know that the frequency would be the same for the both strings ($\omega$), but the wavelength ($\lambda$) would be different in each case. I can split the wave equation in two:

$$\frac{d^2\;\psi_1}{d\;x^2} \frac{T}{\sigma_1} = \frac{d^2\;\psi_1}{d\;t^2}$$

and for the second string (Fe):

$$\frac{d^2\;\psi_2}{d\;x^2} \frac{T}{\sigma_2} = \frac{d^2\;\psi_2}{d\;t^2}\; .$$

$T = mg$ for both cases (there is the same force acting on them) and $\sigma_i = S\rho_i$.

I won't include here the calculation, because it is too long, but my solution to the differential equation is this:

$$\psi_i = c_1e^{i(k_ix + \omega t)} + c_2e^{i(k_ix - \omega t)} + c_3e^{i(-k_ix + \omega t)} + c_4e^{i(-k_ix - \omega t)}\;.$$

As I have explained, I believe $k$ would be different for both strings and $\omega$ the same.

However, there are many unknown coefficients here and I don't know how to move from here. Maybe my approach is even wrong, because the computation looks much more difficult than the problem. What am I doing wrong?